# Preventing a user from disabling or removing a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I made a chrome extension that blocks recommendations on youtube, and also adds a daily time limit, for my brother. But he keeps disabling or removing the chrome extension, is there a way to stop this??

I tried to look for a solution, but I think it is not possible to stop the user form removing or disabling the extension, but is there a way to add password protection to alter with chrome extension settings.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you are allowed to take control of the browser in that way.
You should investigate parental control settings.